# How do you draw a DC equivalent circuit of a circuit which has an AC voltage source and a diode?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, analog

I am studying analog electronics now and I have encountered this problem for my assignment which I have some serious problems solving, wondering if anyone can provide some help. i have searched around the internet and my notes for days but could not really find any real help so thought I turned to this platform.

[image]

> Draw the DC equivalent circuit and determine the DC output voltage VR and current IR through the resistor RL by means of successive iteration method.

Some info for the problem:

- Vdc = 10v
- Vs = 0.1 x cos(5000t)
- r1 = 10 ohm
- rL = 100 ohm
- Vd1 = 0.6v @ Id1 = 1.9mA
- Vd2 = 0.8v @ Id2 = 210mA

**Update:**

For the updates, I found out that to get a DC equivalent circuit, AC voltage sources will be replaced by ground connections. so I tried it out and got the image below:

[image]

Is anyone able to help check if it is correct?

**Update 2:**

I shorted the AC voltage source and proceeded with the successive iteration method. the following picture is my method, and I did arrive at an answer but not sure whether it is correct or luck.

[image]

Comment: What can you say about the details you've been given? Seriously. For example, I can easily see that the diode presents very close to 100 mV per decade of current change. And that's very useful information. Think and express your thoughts here. Help us help you.

Comment: hi, i am not sure what do you mean by 'the diode presents very close to 100 mV per decade of current change'. for me, using the information provided i can get the empirical diode junction equation, Id = ( 1.405x10^-9)e^(Vd/42.5x10^-3).

Comment: Hi Hern, welcome to stack exchange. It's an unwritten rule here that homework questions that don't include an attempt to solve will be closed. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: hi, thanks for the notice. i will update accordingly!

Comment: @HernYiLee Where is your work on the DC iterative solution? Do you imagine doing the AC without that?

Comment: Where did you find the information that AC sources will be replaced by a connection to ground? They will get shorted, so replaced with a line.

Comment: @jonk im still trying to work on it. according to the question, i have to get a dc equivalent circuit before i can use the iterative solution to find the output voltage and current.

Comment: @arsenal i found it in a small section of  my lecture notes. "Obtain DC equivalent circuit by replacing all capacitors by open circuits,
inductors by short circuit, AC voltage sources by ground connections, and
AC current sources by open circuits." thank you very much for your input too, i will try it and see how it goes!

Comment: Your notes are incorrect, @Arsenal is right. Replace an ac voltage source with a short circuit.

Comment: thanks @ElliotAlderson, replaced it and tried it out already!